# Ionic 3 App - Keep logged even when app quits

Tags: authentication, ionic3, exit, stay-logged-in

How to keep logged in application even user closes app? Log in only if user logged out prior to closing application?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid storing the users' passwords at all costs.  It's a bad security practice, not to mention your app would likely not know if they changed their password out of band from your app/session.

If you are using a common token-based authentication, then you can use the concept of **Refresh Tokens** to keep a user logged in.  Effectively when the user logs in the first time, you also request a Refresh Token.  This refresh token can then be used in the future to get another access token without requiring a username/password.  See [this link](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current) for an example implementation from Auth0.  That's the product we use.

Additionally, you should likely not use Refresh Tokens for web-based logins.  For web-based logins it is more common for a user to log in on public devices (or someone else's device).  So keeping them logged in for those scenarios may put your users at higher risk.